# Need padding at the bottom of DIV Elements

Tags: html, css, web

I was working on a simple HTML, CSS design. Need some help with it.
I need a padding at the bottom, but am stuck on where I have to add the padding.

*PS: JSFiddle link at the bottom.*

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="note1" class="notes-note">

    <div id="toolbar1" class="notes-toolbar">
        <div class="notes-title">Title</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content1" class="notes-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Notes */
.notes-note {
    width: 175px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #FFFDD0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Toolbar */
.notes-note .notes-toolbar {
    background-color: #E6E4BC;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
}

/* Title on the Toolbar */
.notes-note .notes-toolbar .notes-title {
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Notes Content */
.notes-note .notes-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Here is the Link to JSFiddle
**[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/SphinX/ZteLW/)**

**EDIT**
The text will be of variying length and also the "**note1**" **DIV Element** will be resizable. So, any solution that will help me in this is much appreciated.

Comment: padding-bottom?? You want to display the box from being hidden or you need spacing for the text that is already hidden??

Comment: specifying a height for `.notes-note .notes-content` seems to work. It's not as neat as a padding but it gives a little 'space' under the actual note.

Comment: I need a little blank space between the text and the bottom of the container.

Comment: what is this 'blank' for ? hide this half-line or extend height of the box ?

Comment: There's large amount of text, I can't extend the height of the box. This is the initial setup of the box. Later on the User will have the ability to resize the note as much as he likes.

Comment: Look at the solution on using a transparent border on the .notes-note.  This give you a very clean padding to the bottom which should work if you users re-size the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply solution is to put a border on the bottom

http://jsfiddle.net/davidja/ZteLW/6/

```
.notes-note {
width: 175px;
height: 100px;
margin: 5px;
background-color: #FFFDD0;
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: solid 10px #fffdd0; // Add This
}
```

Or as Mr Lister pointed out you could use a transparent border. But you will need to use css box-sizing to position the border inside the box - http://jsfiddle.net/davidja/ZteLW/10/

```
.notes-note {
width: 175px;
height: 100px;
margin: 5px;
background-color: #FFFDD0;
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;   //add this
box-sizing : border-box ; //add this   
}
```

Comment: Why not a transparent border, then you won't have to worry about the colour.

Comment: Very true that would be a more flexible solution.

Comment: Simple, but effectiv solution! +1 for the simplicity.

Comment: Yes well done to Mr Lister who solution was even more flexible.

Comment: Yup, the transparent thing did it.  I'm using jQuery & jQueryUI to make the entire thing Draggable and Resizable. Thanks guys..  :)

Answer (score 0):

give it to the id content

```
#content1{
   padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

or the class notes-content

```
.notes-content{
   padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
   // top right bottom left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not say why you need a padding-bottom.

Is it not to show half of a line ?

If so , you need to set line-height according to the numbers of line you want to see in this 100px height:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZteLW/4/ for instance, but this way is not solid if you have different font-size. cause you set height in pixel , so line height shoul be in pixel too.
try this one as well if it fits better to your needs : http://jsfiddle.net/ZteLW/7/

```
/* Notes */
.notes-note {
    width: 175px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #FFFDD0;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height:18px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I need the bottom padding to be constant. Little bit of empty space between the text and the bottom of the Container, looks good.

Comment: oki, i did not get that, to me tops of letters unreadable was kind of not looking good :)

Comment: Oh.. K.. That was a result of *overflow: hidden;* attribute which was hiding the rest of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to wrap the .notes-note class in a container  - and give the container bottom padding.

```
.container
{
   background: #fffdd0;
   padding-bottom: 10px;  
   width: 175px;   
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8XxE9/3/)**

Also i added a few pixels to the height of the .notes-note class so that initially the text isn't cut.

Comment: @GauthamPJ I updated my fiddle with overflow: auto - that's how you deal with the long text

Comment: K.. Thanks for the solution, but I think I'll go with the Bottom padding to the *.notes-note* itself. Seems simpler and is working fine with jQueryUI *resizable* method.